# Azure AD Security pattern between multiple clients

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm struggling to understand exactly what Microsoft documentation I need to read through in order to implement a particular set of security patterns so I was hoping someone could help me rubber duck it and understand what I need to consider.

**Clients:**

UWP Desktop Application
ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web application

**Services:**

Azure Key Vault
Azure App Registration

**What I'm trying to accomplish is this:**

The UWP app calls and authenticates against Azure AAD and receives an `AccessToken`

It makes calls to an authenticated API controller endpoint in the ASP.net core web application which should validate the `AccessToken` to ensure it was issued by the current organisation domain and tenant.

At the same time, the Web Application is also a web based portal to access the same services as the UWP, if a user navigates to it, it should display the Microsoft Sign In pages and pass back the `AccessToken` So that a web user can access various controller routes.

**What I've looked at:**

[Microsoft Documentation - Protecting Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration)

[Microsoft Git Repo Exmaples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph)

**The code I've currently got set up:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // I've removed the parts of this section that are not relevant.

    // Authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        // This is a Microsoft identity platform web API.
        options.Authority += "/v2.0";

        // The web API accepts as audiences both the Client ID (options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}.
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[]
        {
             options.Audience,
             $"api://{options.Audience}"
        };


        // Instead of using the default validation (validating against a single tenant,
        // as we do in line-of-business apps),
        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic (which even accepts both v1 and v2 tokens).
        options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.ValidateAadIssuer;
    });
}
```

This is the validator class that was taken from the Git Repo.

```
public class AadIssuerValidator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validate the issuer for multi-tenant applications of various audience (Work and School account, or Work and School accounts +
    /// Personal accounts)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="issuer">Issuer to validate (will be tenanted)</param>
    /// <param name="securityToken">Received Security Token</param>
    /// <param name="validationParameters">Token Validation parameters</param>
    /// <remarks>The issuer is considered as valid if it has the same http scheme and authority as the
    /// authority from the configuration file, has a tenant Id, and optionally v2.0 (this web api
    /// accepts both V1 and V2 tokens).
    /// Authority aliasing is also taken into account</remarks>
    /// <returns>The <c>issuer</c> if it's valid, or otherwise <c>SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException</c> is thrown</returns>
    public static string ValidateAadIssuer(string issuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
        if (jwtToken == null)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Expecting a JWT Token from Azure Active Directory.");
        }

        // Extracting the tenant ID
        string tenantId = jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "tid")?.Value;
        if (jwtToken == null)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Expecting a tid claim from Azure Active Directory.");
        }

        // Build the valid tenanted issuers
        List<string> allValidIssuers = new List<string>();

        IEnumerable<string> validIssuers = validationParameters.ValidIssuers;
        if (validIssuers != null)
        {
            allValidIssuers.AddRange(validIssuers.Select(i => TenantedIssuer(i, tenantId)));
        }

        string validIssuer = validationParameters.ValidIssuer;
        if (validIssuer != null)
        {
            allValidIssuers.Add(TenantedIssuer(validIssuer, tenantId));
        }

        // Consider the aliases (https://login.microsoftonline.com (v2.0 tokens) => https://sts.windows.net (v1.0 tokens) )
        allValidIssuers.AddRange(allValidIssuers.Select(i => i.Replace("https://login.microsoftonline.com", "https://sts.windows.net")).ToArray());

        // Consider tokens provided both by v1.0 and v2.0 issuers
        allValidIssuers.AddRange(allValidIssuers.Select(i => i.Replace("/v2.0", "/")).ToArray());

        if (!allValidIssuers.Contains(issuer))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Issuer does not match the valid issuers");
        }
        else
        {
            return issuer;
        }
    }

    private static string TenantedIssuer(string i, string tenantId)
    {
        return i.Replace("{tenantid}", tenantId);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm hitting is that when I navigate the user to the home/index route they are getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
>   there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

I'm assuming this is because the docs and the git repo are assuming that the WebAPI is just that, and it doesn't also contain a front end etc.

Any advice would be great because I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**Edit:**

From the looks of it, I don't think it's possible to have the secure API sat in the same instance as the website, so In the end I split them out into their own Web Apps and that seems to work fine, just seems to feel a bit like we are doubling up on authentication logic between the overall solution. Happy if someone corrects me here.